# I was wondering if it's possible to implement card.js on WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm usgin Woocommerce + Stripe for Woocommerce and the credit card form looks simple/ugly and found this https://github.com/jessepollak/card (demo: https://jessepollak.github.io/card/ ) so I've tried placing the card folder into my child theme and then calling it with script tags but it didn't work.

Accordint to the example this is how I should call it

```
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/card.js"></script>
<script>
    new Card({
        form: document.querySelector('form'),
        container: '.card-wrapper'
    });
</script>
```

And then using the card-wrapper style where I need it. But at the end I've place the script in a glbal js on WordPress, the card.js was in a folder named card inside my child-theme but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any lights.

Comment: Thank you for the question, Jorge, but 3rd party themes/plugins/libraries are off topic here on WPSE. I do expect that it is possible to use this fancy script with WP and WooCommerce though. The first step in troubleshooting JS libraries is to be sure they are being loaded. In WP, it's best to use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) instead of hard coding script tags in your theme/plugin. Make sure that the path is correct to the JS file and ensure that it's being loaded by the browser using dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have misplaced the card jquery library. You can include the js using [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) in WordPress.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-card-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/card.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
```

Use the above code in your child theme functions.php and 
call your card from your main js file.

```
new Card({
        form: document.querySelector('form'),
        container: '.card-wrapper'
    });
```